# Filter table with a column in Laravel Backpack

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a Employee table which display like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
|  id  |    name    |   code    |
---------------------------------
|  1   | Employee 1 |    A1     |
|  2   | Employee 2 |    A2     |
| ...  |    ...     |   ...     |
+-------------------------------+
```

And I want to create a filter by code column in this table. My query will be like this:

```sql
SELECT name FROM employee WHERE code LIKE .% $filter %.
```

I searched in backpack document and trying to do like this

```php
$this->crud->addFilter(
    [
        'type' => 'select2',
        'name' => 'code',
        'label' => 'Filter',
    ],
    function () {
        return Employee::select('code')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
    },
    function ($value) {
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'code', $value);
    }
);
```

But it got error: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. How I can fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of where the `htmlspecialchars` error is coming from?

Comment: This is my full error: ""htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\fox-steps-admin-master\vendor\backpack\crud\src\resources\views\filters\select2.blade.php)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code to generate the list of employee codes is returning an array like this at the moment, while the package is expecting an array of strings.

```php
[
    ['code' => 'A1'],
    ['code' => 'A2'],
];
```

To fix the issue, you need to `pluck` the `code` column from the array, and key it by the code:

```php
$this->crud->addFilter([
        'type' => 'select2',
        'name' => 'code',
        'label' => 'Filter',
    ],
    function() {
        return Employee::select('code')->distinct()->get()->pluck('code', 'code')->toArray();
    },
    function($value) {
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'code', $value);
    });
```

This will result in something like:

```php
[
    'A1' => 'A1',
    'A2' => 'A2',
];
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I can get the list of code to filter now. But when I choose a code to filter, in my url, it will get the number to filter like this employee?code=0. I need to use the name like employee?code=A1. Can I do this?

Comment: Hmm, strange. Could you post the output of the query `Employee::select('code')->distinct()->get()->pluck('code', 'code')->toArray()`

Comment: You can test it with `php artisan tinker`

Comment: it's work! I fixed pluck('code') into pluck('code','code'). Thank you very much!